# Transfering an keycloak mapper to another realm

Tags: keycloak, mapper

I hope you are doing fine. I have set up multiple realms in my Keycloak instance and would like to transfer an specific custom mapper between these realms. Under client scopes -> Mappers, I can only find the manually integrated mapper in the master realm, not in the others, without having consciously specified it beforehand. I am using version 20.0.5. I tried to find an option in the GUI, but it seems that the "copy" option was removed in a previous version.

Thank you in advance. Best regards!